# Sorting IterableStorageMap

Tags: substrate, polkadot

IterableStorageMap doesn't support ordering. How to sort the values of IterableStorageMap in ascending or descending order?

https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0/frame_support/storage/trait.IterableStorageMap.html

Comment: For small storage maps you could collect into a vec and then sort.
My recommendation would be to insert items in the right order or not rely on ordering, though.

Comment: If you want to maintain a sorted data structure, a map seems like a weird choice. I agree with @apopiak that you should use a vector and maintain it in sorted order. This Recipe may offer some inspiration https://substrate.dev/recipes/vec-set.html

Comment: Ya got it. "To ensure reasonable performance, we will enforce that the Vec always remains sorted"